# When using ND filter, do I need to use full stop, 1/2 stop, or 1/3 stop?

Tags: neutral-density

For example, when I use ND1000 filter, I know theoretically I have to increase shutter speed by 10 stops. Does this apply regardless of different stop increment settings (full stop vs half stop vs 1/3-stop), or do they say 10 stop in full stop increment?

Comment: What exactly do the instructions say that came with the ND Filter?

Comment: @AlaskaMan No instructions came with the filter. FYI, I use NiSi EX Color ND1000 (screw-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing "stops" with "steps". A photographic stop is a doubling of light exposure.

If you can adjust your exposure by 1/2- or 1/3- stop increments, then you would need 2 or 3 *increments* adjustment (respectively) to achieve a **1 stop** change in exposure. So when using a 10-stop ND filter, you would need 20 steps if you were adjusting in 1/2-stop increments, or 30 steps if using 1/3-stop increments.

If you were shooting a scene, without ND filter, and your exposure settings dictated a 2-second shutter speed, then a 10-stop ND filter would necessitate increasing the exposure by a factor of 2<sup>10</sup> (i.e., 1024). Thus, you'd set the shutter speed to 2 * 1024 = 2048 = 34.133... min = 34:08.

<sup>**Note:** a ND1024 filter is precisely a 10-stop (i.e., 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 multiplier) ND filter. A ND1000 is actually a multiple of 1000, not 1024. Thus the change from 2-second non-ND exposure would be 2 * 1000 = 33.33... min = 33:20. However, the ratio difference of 1024/1000 is only 2.4%. In terms of stops, the difference is log<sub>2</sub>(1.024) = 0.034 stops, a trivially small exposure difference that you won't be able to discern between two images, and way below the smallest precision of any commercially-available DSLR or MILC camera.</sup>

---

Regarding fractional-stop ND filters, they aren't common, but they do exist. I use mostly Lee filters. While I don't own fractional-stop filters, Lee makes ND 0.45 (1.5 stop) and ND 0.75 (2.5 stop) filters. If one were to use either of those filters, the exposure settings would need to be adjusted by 2<sup>1.5</sup> ≈ 2.83, or 2<sup>2.5</sup> ≈ 5.66, respectively.

---

Now, regarding fractional-stop exposure settings in camera: it doesn't matter if your camera is able to set exposure settings in fractional-stop increments. Whatever the "correct"/desired exposure settings a particular scene calls for without a ND filter in front of the lens, you need to increase the total exposure by the number of stops as called for when using your filter.

For instance, let's say a particular ISO 100, ƒ/8 shot is metered for 1/50" . A 10-stop ND filter would still require increasing the shutter duration from 1/50" to 1/50 * 1024 = 20.48 seconds. I'm not aware of any cameras or shutter remotes that allow fractional seconds beyond 2.5", so you can just pick 20 or 21 seconds. The difference is only 0.07 stops (i.e., less than <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> stop, still less than any camera can control for).

Related questions and links:

- [Are neutral density ratings in 1/3 stops or are they really in 0.3 stops?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71790/15871)
- [How to read ND filter description?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30135/15871)
- [Choosing between 9-stop and 10-stop ND filter for flowing water long exposures](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106417/choosing-between-9-stop-and-10-stop-nd-filter-for-flowing-water-long-exposures) — While you aren't asking the same question, the answers address similar concerns where a small difference in stop calculations don't matter as much with 10+ stop ND filters as it does with 1–3 stop (or so) ND filters.
- [Neutral-density filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral-density_filter#ND_filter_ratings) article at Wikipedia. The "ND filter ratings" section in particular is useful regarding the different nomenclature for ND filter strengths used by different filter manufacturers.

Comment: And, given that the whole stop sequence is a series of approximations, and that the 10-stop ND filter may not be _exactly_ 10 stops, but maybe 9.7 or 10.2, you might need anywhere from 19-21 or 29-31 steps, respectively. Or maybe even a little less/more...

Comment: @twalberg _especially_ so at the higher end of the ND filter range (10, 13, 16, etc.). The variation in optical density of 1-stop to say 3-stop filters is a lot less than the potential variation of NDs like the Big Stoppers.

Comment: @scottbb yes you are right - I misspelled the step with "stop" in my original question (my bad), sorry for confusion. Anyway, let's say I get a good exposure with shutter speed of 2'' - is it approximately correct to adjust it to 2'' * 1000 / 60'' = 33' when I use ND1000 filter?

Comment: @elquimista Correct reasoning, close-but-not-exact math. Assuming the ND1000 filter is accurately 10 stops, then 10 doublings = 2^10 = 1024. So 2 * 1024 = 34.133... = 34' 8" (34:08). But your reasoning is correct. However, the exposure difference between a factor of 1000 and a factor 1024 is only 2.4%, which comes out to only 0.03 stops, well below the smallest precision any commercial DSLR/MILC can reproduce.

Comment: @elquimista I meant to add (not regarding the math), no worries about "step" vs. "stop". The terminology can be confusing, especially because of the additive concept of stops mapping to the multiplicative mapping to powers of 2 (i.e., mapping logarithms to exponents). =)

Comment: @scottbb Thanks for quick reply. So that calculation mechanism doesn't involve differentiating between full-stop, half-stop, 1/3-stop increments? If yes, this would be simpler, quicker solution for me

Comment: @elquimista It would only matter if you had a ND filter with some fraction of stops. I'm not aware of many filters that do, but they exist. For instance, I use Lee filters. They use the "ND.number" notation, where every multiple of 0.3 = 1 stop. So their ND 0.3 = 1 stop filter, ND 0.6 = 2 stops, etc. They have a ND 0.45 and ND 0.75, corresponding to 1.5 and 2.5 stops filters, respectively. If I were using those filters with a 2" exposure, I'd need 2 * 2^1.5 = 5.66s and 2^2.5 = 11.3s exposures.

Comment: @elquimista Just making sure I'm precise in what I'm saying to you: regardless of whatever exposure settings your camera currently has (for instance, maybe you're not set at a standard (full-stop) aperture or shutter setting), if the ND filter calls for an even number of stops, then you need to adjust the exposure (time and/or aperture, combined) by that same number of stops. So if your non-ND exposure is 2.5s, then w/ a 10-stop filter, you need to multiply the time by 2^10=1024. The 2.5-stop ND I mentioned previously would require an adjustment factor of 2^2.5=5.66.

Comment: @elquimista In the field, I find that a ND exposure calculator app on my phone is quite useful. I tend to do most of the calculations in my head (I'm a software engineer, so I'm quite comfortable with multiples of powers of 2). I use my phone app to double-check my head calculations.

Comment: BTW, the different ND filter notations are also covered here in [Are neutral density ratings in 1/3 stops or are they really in 0.3 stops?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71790/15871) and [How to read ND filter description?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30135/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC Thank you. I normally prefer to make my reference links to other Photo-SE questions rather than off-site. I spaced it this time. =)  I removed my WP-link.

Comment: Well, some of the answers at each of those SE questions *do* point to the chart at the bottom of the wikipedia article...

Comment: @MichaelC Yeah. I know you've made the argument in the past (strongly, I might add) that "see also" links should try to direct references to questions at PSE. Or at least, to PSE questions _first_. I'm editing my answer now to basically address all of these comments anyways, including your reference links. Thanks for picking up my lazy slack. =)